# Python: specify return type of class method that works with inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, typing, class-method

I've been trying to understand how I can specify the return type of a class method in Python, such that it is interpreted correctly (e.g. in my Sphinx documentation) even for child classes.

Suppose I had:

```
class Parent:

    @classmethod
    def a_class_method(cls) -> 'Parent':
        return cls()


class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

What should I specify as the return type of `a_class_method` if I want it to be `Parent` for the parent and `Child` for the child? I've also tried `__qualname__`, but that doesn't seem to work either. Should I just not annotate the return type?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13):

[There's supported syntax for that now](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#annotating-instance-and-class-methods), by annotating `cls` with a type variable. Quoting one of the examples from PEP 484:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound='C')
class C:
    @classmethod
    def factory(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
        # make a new instance of cls

class D(C): ...
d = D.factory()  # type here should be D
```

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. In the Sphinx documentation, it's writing the return type as "T", rather than as the type of the corresponding subclass, but I guess that's okay, if I think of T as standing for "the same type as the class".

Do you know if it's common practice to actually call that TypeVar "T"? And if so, what would be the standard practice for when there are multiple classes in the same module that you would want to do this with?